# Distinct Conditional Counting to Avoid Overlap

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Consider this table:

```
[Table1]
------------------------
| Person_ID | Yes | No |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     1     |  1  | 0  |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     1     |  1  | 0  |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     2     |  0  | 1  |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     2     |  0  | 1  |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     3     |  1  | 0  |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     3     |  1  | 0  |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     3     |  0  | 1  |
|-----------|-----|----|
|     3     |  1  | 0  |
------------------------
```

I need a distinct count on `Person_ID` to get the number of people that are marked `Yes` and `No`. However, if someone has a single instance of `No`, they should be counted as a `No` and not be included in the `Yes` count no matter how many `Yes` they have.

My first thought was to try something similar to:

```
select count(distinct (case when Yes = 1 then Person_ID else null end)) Yes_People
     , count(distinct (case when No = 1 then Person_ID else null end)) No_People
from Table1
```

but this will result in 3 being counted in both the `Yes` and `No` counts.

My desired output would be:

```
--------------------------
| Yes_People | No_People |
|------------|-----------|
|      1     |     2     |
--------------------------
```

I'm hoping to avoid the performance hit from having to evaluate a subquery against each row but if it has to be the way to go I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group them by the person.
Then the `CASE` for the `Yes` people can have a not `No` condition.

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN No = 0 AND Yes = 1 THEN Person_ID END) AS Yes_People,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN No = 1 THEN Person_ID END) AS No_People
FROM 
(
     select Person_ID
     , MAX(Yes) as Yes
     , MAX(No) as No
     FROM Table1
     GROUP BY Person_ID
) q
```

Comment: Thx.  Btw, just my oppinion. But if this is from some questionnaire, then I would assume that the last answer of the person is the valid one. But then the table would need some timestamp. And the query would need stuff like ROW_NUMBER to get the latest response.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate first at the person level and then overall:

```
select sum(yes_only) as yes_only,
       sum(1 - yes_only) as no
from (select person_id,
             (case when max(yes) = min(yes) and max(yes) = 1
                   then 1
              end) as yes_only
      from t
      group by person_id
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a window function to rank the rows for a single person_id to prioritize a 'No' over a 'Yes', but that will require a subquery

```
select count(case when yes=1 then 1 end) as yes_count, 
 count(case when no=1 then no_count) as no_count
from (
   select person_id, yes, no, row_number() over (order by no desc, yes desc) as rn
   from table1
) 
where rn = 1
```

The inner subquery plus the `where` filter will get you a single row per person_id, giving priority to the 'no' records.

This of course assumes yes/no are mutually exclusive, and if that's true, you should probably change the model to a single field.

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to precheck every person with a window function

```
with t as (select 1 p_id, 1 yes, 0 no from dual
   union all select 1 p_id, 1 yes, 0 no from dual
   union all select 2 p_id, 0 yes, 1 no from dual
   union all select 2 p_id, 0 yes, 1 no from dual
   union all select 3 p_id, 1 yes, 0 no from dual
   union all select 3 p_id, 0 yes, 1 no from dual
   union all select 3 p_id, 1 yes, 0 no from dual)
, chk as (
   select max(no) over (partition by p_id)  n
        , max(yes) over (partition by p_id) y
        , p_id
   from   t)
--   select * from chk;
   select count(distinct decode(y-n,1,p_id,null )) yes_people
        , count(distinct decode(n,1,p_id,null )) no_people
   from chk
   group by 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional aggregation as following:

> ```
> SQL> with table1 as (select 1 PERSON_ID, 1 yes, 0 no from dual
>   2     union all select 1 PERSON_ID, 1 yes, 0 no from dual
>   3     union all select 2 PERSON_ID, 0 yes, 1 no from dual
>   4     union all select 2 PERSON_ID, 0 yes, 1 no from dual
>   5     union all select 3 PERSON_ID, 1 yes, 0 no from dual
>   6     union all select 3 PERSON_ID, 0 yes, 1 no from dual
>   7     union all select 3 PERSON_ID, 1 yes, 0 no from dual)
>   8  SELECT
>   9      SUM(CASE WHEN NOS = 0 AND YES > 0 THEN 1 END) YES_PEOPLE,
>  10      SUM(CASE WHEN NOS > 0 THEN 1 END) NO_PEOPLE
>  11  FROM
>  12     (
>  13      SELECT
>  14          SUM(NO) NOS,
>  15          PERSON_ID,
>  16          SUM(YES) YES
>  17      FROM TABLE1
>  18     GROUP BY PERSON_ID
>  19     );
>
> YES_PEOPLE  NO_PEOPLE
> ---------- ----------
>          1          2
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!